# Sending email attachment android with intent. Only works in Gmail

Tags: android, email, android-intent, xamarin.android, email-attachments

I am trying to send a .png file with an Android intent. I have tried saving this file in internal storage with WorldReadable permissions and now have saved to the external storage. When I open the GMail client my attachment is there. However, in Microsoft Exchange or Outlook app the attachment does not appear and I have to add it manually.

I'm using Xamarin.Android (MonoDroid) but any java solutions would be helpful as well.
Here is my code for sending the email with the intent.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.setType("image/png"); // I also tried 'application/image'
        intent.setData(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("mailto:" + address ?? string.Empty));

        if (!string.isNullOrEmpty (attachment)) {
            intent.putExtra (Android.Content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Android.Net.Uri.fromFile(new Java.IO.File (Android.OS.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), attachment)));
        }

        try {
            _Context.startActivity(intent);
        }catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

            //Show prompt
        }
```

I'm not sure why the attachment only shows up in GMail. Do I need a content provider? It's weird that its only showing up in GMail and not any other mail applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't need a ContentProvider.

I'm doing the basically the same thing for sending a JPEG, but using `Intent.ActionSend` instead of `Intent.ActionSendTo`.

Comment: In addition to setting the intent to Intent.ActionSend I had to change the email address to intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraEmail, 'email@email.com');

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) 
    {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.cstand);
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        System.out.println("PATH : "+sdCard);
        File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Salary/Documents/Email");//#2

        dir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(dir, "Document.png");

        try 
        {
            output = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            String subject = "Document" ;
            String message = "Please, see the attcahed document";

            //FOR EMAIL
            Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.fromParts("mailto", "", null));
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose any Email:"));

            }
        catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you also add some context / explanation please?

Comment: U need Permissions in the Manifest   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  You can only attach an image to mail if the image is located in the SDCARD. So, you'll need to copy the image to SD or create on the fly and then attach it. 
I just tried it and it worked for me, hope it helps! Please accept if it does :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ActionSendMultiple Intent: `Intent(Intent.ActionSendMultiple)`.

For attachments use `PutParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, uris)` where uris variable is a `List<IParcelable>()`.

Here's an example:

```
var email = new Intent(Intent.ActionSendMultiple);
    email.SetType("text/plain");
    email.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraEmail, new string[]{emailTo});
    email.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraCc, new string[]{emailCC});

    var uris = new List<IParcelable>();
    filePaths.ForEach(file=> {
        var fileIn = new File(file);
        var uri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(fileIn);
        uris.Add(uri);
    });

    email.PutParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, uris);

    context.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(email, "Send mail..."));
```

Hope this helps ;)